# How to make a button copy data from a cells to a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm making a machine move tracker in work, but I'm new to excel coding.

I have multiple sells of data I want to insert to a table with the click of a button, image attached of the input data form.

any help with what button to use or macro coding to make this possible would be great.
or if anyone knows of a source for help creating macros, please hit me up

thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRZec.png)

Comment: Welcome! Are you sure you want to do it yourself? Perhaps the [**built-in Form tool**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/data_form.html) is suitable for your purposes and it will be enough?

Comment: @JohnSUN That link is for Libreoffice, the asker is using Excel :)

Comment: @MiG Let's think it was an unobtrusive advertisement for an alternative office :). Yes, actually I was mistaken - the link should lead [**there**](https://trumpexcel.com/data-entry-form/).

Comment: @APRICE94 - welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. I have answered your question here for once.

Comment: The question is not very clearly, you should provide the data source and the output table.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @JohnSUN there are build-in tools. This also exists with Microsoft Excel and its use is recommended by me. But, of course you may want to learn VBA and add forms by yourself later.

Customize your quick access toolbar and add the `Form` icon.

[image]

Use the form dialog as shown below to add new data items.

[image]